# What is preventing me from deploying this smart contract?

Tags: javascript, deployment, solidity, smartcontracts

I have been following along and referencing an updated version of the repository of this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wn_Kb3MR_cU&list=PLBx8Eyw3km2mpbKPhoTDVYjM6TpvYCdv0. GitHub https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_web3.0/tree/main And around an hour and thirty two minutes in, when it's time to deploy the contract to the testnet, I get this message;

```
 npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia 

Compiled 2 Solidity files successfully
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployed", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.7)
    at makeError (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:670:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:706:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:542:23)
    at buildWrappedMethod (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:342:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:870:22)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:768:39)
    at main (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\scripts\deploy.js:5:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runMain (C:\Users\Web3_Proj1\smart_contract\scripts\deploy.js:12:5) {

  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',

  argument: 'key',

  value: 'deployed'

}
```

In the video and in the repository they use the ropsten testnet but I used the sepolia in mine; so please rule that out.

Please give any suggestions on how to get this deployed.

Answer (score 0):

In the above video, the tutor has removed the hardhat import from the deploy.js file, but it is needed for running any scripts, please import it `const hre = require("hardhat");` and try. It should work. You can follow this official documentation for more information about how to do it without using getContractFactory function. https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/scripts#standalone-scripts:-using-hardhat-as-a-library